# How to re-show a Matplotlib plot in Jupyter notebooks without duplicating code

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way I can save a plot to a variable, and show it at multiple points in a notebook? Say I create a plot near the start of a notebook, then wayyyyy further down in the analysis it'd be relevant to look at that plot again.

Something like:

```
my_plot = plt.plot(plot_params)
plt.show()
```

Then later call:

```
plt.clf()
my_plot
plt.show()
```

This doesn't work, and I'm confused as to why, since the call to `plt.plot(plot_params)` should be stored in `my_plot`.

Comment: `my_plot` only holds a temporary reference to some lines in the subplot. You need to define a function. E.g. `def my_plot_func():  plt.plot(plot_params)` and then call that function twice.

Comment: I think it’s possible display(fig) works? Where fig is a reference to the figure.

Answer (score 0):

[`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) returns a list of lines, not the plot itself. The plot itself is called a `Figure` in matplotlib. So you need to get this Figure and store it in a variable:

```
my_fig = my_plot[0].figure
```

To show it later in your Jupyter notebook, just type it as `my_fig`:

[image]

(or you keep your variable `my_plot` and get the figure later when you want to re-show it by `my_plot[0].figure`)